# How to make the white background of the pdf page transparent with FPDF - PHP

Tags: php, transparency, fpdf

I am using FPDF to generate a pdf. I am placing an image onto the A4 page layout and do not want to see the white page background. Is it possible to make this transparent?

I have tried the following code below, but this also sets any subsequent image added to the page also transparent.

PHP with the following script ([click here for script](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script74.php))

```
$pdf = new AlphaPDF('P','pt','A4');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetAlpha(0);
```